# How to change checkbox value in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have one gridview. In this gridview one column itemtemplate has check box. I want to change the text of checkbox during check or unchecking the check box.

Can any on help the code.

Thanks In advance
Eshwer

Answer (score 0):

you should be use **TemplateField** for display your checkbox:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="headerText">                                       
      <ItemTemplate>
          // your image or text for display checked or not
          <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isView")=="True"?"IS CHECKED":"NOT CHECKED" %>'></asp:Label>                    
      </ItemTemplate>

      <EditTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox DataField="isView" runat="server" />
      </EditTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```